# Matlab Histogram Function

Tags: matlab, histogram

I'm new to Matlab and for an assignment my professor is having the class write (complete really) a custom Matlab function for generating a histogram from a set of data. Essentially a new vector is being created, `L` which is being updated with the information from a 2D matrix `M`. The first column of `L` contains the information from `M(i,j)` and in a second column contains the count (total) of `M(i,j)` in the data set. I'm in need of some direction as to how to proceed next.

Below is where I'm at thus far:

```
function L = hist_count(M)

L = [ [0:255' zeros(256,1) ];
for i = 1:size(M,1)
    for j = 1:size(M,2)
        L(double(M(i,j))+1,2) = <<finish code here>>;
    end
end

figure;
plot(L(:1),L(:2));
```

The `<<finish code here>>` section is where I'm stuck. I understand everything up to the point where I need to update `L` with the information.

Assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Your brackets are mismatched in your initialization of `L`. Why are you incrementing the index into the histogram? You should probably modify the *value* of the current index instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note:* Your initialization of your histogram `L` has the brackets mismatched. 
 Remove the second `[` bracket in the code.  In addition, the creation of the `0:255` vector is incorrect.  Doing `0:255'` transposes the single constant of 255, which means that it will still create a horizontal vector of `0:255` which will make the code fail.  You should surround the creation of this vector with parantheses, then transpose that result.  Therefore:

```
L = [ (0:255)' zeros(256,1) ];
```

Now onto your actual problem.  Judging by your initialization of the histogram, there are 256 possible values so your input is most likely of type `uint8`, which means that the values in your data will only be from `[0-255]` in steps of 1.  Recall that a histogram records the total number of times you see a value.  In this case, you have a two column matrix where the first column tells you the value you want to examine and the second column tells you how many times you see that value in your data.  Therefore, each row tells you which value you are examining in your data as well as how many times you have seen that value in your data.  Note that the counts are all initialized to zero, so the logic is that every time you see a value, you need to access the right row corresponding to the data point, then increment that value by 1.

Therefore, the line is simply just accessing the current count and adding 1 to it... you then store it back:

```
L(double(M(i,j))+1,2) = L(double(M(i,j))+1,2) + 1;
```

`M(i,j)` is the value found at location `(i,j)` in your 2D data.  The last question you have is why cast the intensity to `double` and add 1?  You cast to `double` because the input may be an integer type.  This means that any values that are beyond the dynamic range of the type will get saturated.  Because your input is type `uint8`, any values beyond 255 will saturate to 255.  In MATLAB, we index into rows and columns of a matrix starting at 1 and because the values will potentially start at value 0, this corresponds to row 1 of your histogram so you have to offset by 1.  When we get to the most extreme case of value 255 for type `uint8` for example, adding 1 to this using the native `uint8` will saturate to 255, which means that the values of 254 and 255 get lumped into the same bin.  Therefore, you must convert to some type that extends beyond the limits of `uint8` and then you add by 1 to avoid saturation.  `double` is usually done here as a default as it has higher precision than `uint8`, but any type that is higher than `uint8` in precision is suitable.

Comment: Thank you for the response, it is extremely helpful. However, I cannot fully implement at this time due to an error: `Error using horzcat Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent`. Can you assist in showing me how to proceed from here?

Comment: Ah, that's because the vector of `0:255` is wrong.  Please surround it with parantheses: `(0:255)'`. What's happening is that it's creating a horizontal vector by transposing the single constant of 255, which is not correct.  I'll update my post.

Comment: Ah! Oversight on my part, I believe that is why the [ was maligned, there were supposed to be two surrounding `0:255`. Worked perfect! Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewR. No problem at all.  I should have noticed that.  Oops.  I'm glad you figured it out and you're welcome!